# How can I fix my script to avoid “[Yes: command not found”?

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
[$(echo -e "No\nYes" | dmenu -i -p "$1") = "Yes"] && "$2"
```

I am trying to write a prompt script to aid in shutdown and other functions, but whenever I run it with two args it returns this:

```
<r0x0r|scripts>$ ./script.sh "Are you sure" "htop"
./script.sh: line 3: [Yes: command not found
```

Comment: welcome to U&L, just add space arround [ and ]

Comment: the title needs to be changed here to something more searchable